# Read gzip file into array without unzipping in node js

Tags: node.js, gzip

How can I read a .gz file into an array in nodejs without having to unzip?

It is simple to do in PHP by using "gzfile", is there an equivalent in nodejs?

I attempted with this code below but myarray does not print out and I am not sure it is the best method:

```
const fs       = require('fs');
const zlib     = require('zlib');
const readline = require('readline');

let lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('myfile.gz').pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
});

let n = 0;
var myarray =[];
lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
myarray[n]=line;
  n += 1
  console.log("line: " + n);
  console.log(line);
});

console.log(myarray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `console.log(myarray)` is executed even before any `'line'` event has come and a blank array is printed in console. You could promisify the event listener but I guess you would only be able to `await` the first event. You could use an alternative solution to read the lines into `myarray` which is based on the [example](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) in the official nodejs doc.

```
const fs       = require('fs');
const zlib     = require('zlib');
const readline = require('readline');

const lineF = (path) => readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
});

var myarray = [];
const myFunction = async () => {
    for await (const line of lineF("myfile.gz")) {
      myarray.push(line);
    }
}

(async () => {
    await myFunction();
    console.log(myarray);
})();
```